# How do you produce a Storyboard header that doesn't scroll with the table beneath it and doesn't bounce on refresh?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, storyboard

So initially I had a View/TableViewCell in the table's hierarchy as the header. This View/TableViewCell scrolled with the other cell in the table and bounced on refresh. By moving the View/TableViewCell outside of the table's hierarchy, it correctly no longer scrolls down with the other cell in the table. However, on refresh it still bounces.

So, since the View/TableViewCell isn't inside a table where bounce can be disabled, how do I get the desired outcome of having the View/TableViewCell header not scroll and not bounce on refresh. This is my storyboard:

[Storyboard of the View/TableViewCell that I want as header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JK9b.png)

Comment: Just to clarify... you want a view above the first row of your table, and you want it to always be visible... and you don't want it to "bounce down" when the table is dragged down?

Comment: I hat about just adding a view above the table?

Comment: @DonMag yes that is correct

Comment: @CloudBalancing But I already have that, right? My storyboard is in the link at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track...

Difficult to tell from the image you posted, but what you want to do is use a `UIViewController` ... ***NOT*** a `UITableViewController`. Then you can add a view as your "header view" at the top, and add a `UITableView` below that "header view."

Here's how it might be laid-out:

[image]

---

**Edit** - *after comments...*

Do ***NOT*** try to edit the XML of your Storyboard. Unless you know exactly what you're doing (including all of the quirks and intricacies of that XML), you're just asking for trouble.

You can copy/paste (or directly move) UI elements.

The approach I would take, starting with this Storyboard (a `UITableViewController` with a cell Prototype):

[image]

Add a new `UIViewController` to your Storyboard:

[image]

Add and constrain your "header" view:

[image]

Add and constrain a `UITableView`:

[image]

Now drag the cell Prototype from the `UITableViewController` to the table view in your new `UIViewController`:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Now you can delete your original table view controller... assign your class to the new view controller... make sure you have all `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` connections set... re-connect any segues you need... etc.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much to the end of the project so I can't really change it to UIViewController without having to change/undo a boatload of stuff. Is there any way to get this done while keeping UITableViewController?

Comment: @florida27 - I'd think it would take less than 5 minutes to make the change. However, if you **really** want to avoid that, I don't see a way to accomplish your goal in Storyboard. In code, you could add your "header view" and manage its position, but there will be other aspects that will be tricky to handle. If you don't mind disabling `bounces` on the table view, you could make your "header view" a table view section header.

Comment: It seems you were right, there weren't that many changes to get it to run with UIViewController. So now my class in the .swift page is class homepage: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: The weird thing is that the icons for the scene and ViewController in Storyboard are still not VC but rather TableVC. That is just Storyboard being finicky I assume. Then it leaves getting the header to stay fixed. I have my hierarchy like yours, but even with VC class, it does not stay fixed. Was is the L HeaderViewSubview and constraints that made yours fixed?

Comment: @florida27 - If you had a `UITableViewController` in your Storyboard, you cannot just re-assign its class to `UIViewController`... you need to delete it and add a new `UIViewController`. The `L` is just a `UILabel`, with center constraints. The `ViewAsHeader` is a `UIView`, constrained Top / Leading / Trailing with a Height of `40`.

Comment: Aah gotcha. So I managed to edit the XML of the Storyboard and now it shows as a `UIViewController` and not a `UITableViewController ` Now a just need to change my `TableView-TableViewCell` hierarchy to your `UIView-TableView-TableViewCell` hierarchy. Is there any way to do that without deleting my current `TableViewCell`?

Comment: @florida27 - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That is a lot easier, you are right. Just one issue, how does one move the refresh control that is in the current tableViewController to the table of the viewController. Since viewController can't take a refresh control like tableViewController, I will have to move it to the table

Comment: @florida27 - I'm sure you can search and find how to do this and implement it yourself in a couple minutes, but here's a basic example: https://pastebin.com/LxCRAcWw

Comment: sorry for late reply, I forgot about the question. It works well